# Using Flexnav on a custom wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming

Hi I'm creating my own theme on wordpress and have been running into difficulty creating a dynamic menu. I want to use the flexnav menu (http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/), which I can display through a static site but when trying to implement it through wordpress I can not display the sub menus and dropdown class elements, can anyone help or has anyone had the same problem with dropdown menus?

Comment: This is what my header.php looks like

Comment: <!----- Nav ----->
   <div id="navbar">
 <div class="container">  

  <div class='menu-button'>Menu</div> 
  <nav id"nav" role="navigation">
    <!-- dynamic wordpress nav --> 
          <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu_id' => 'nav',
    'menu_class' => 'flexnav', //Adding the class for FlexNav
    'items_wrap' => '<ul data-breakpoint="800" id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>', // Adding data-breakpoint for FlexNav
    )); ?> 
          <!-- end dynamic wordpress nav -->           
  </nav>

Comment: @jopfre Im not sure how to display the css here but this is a link to a test page for the nav... flexnav.ml

Comment: <?php
// Create a function for register_nav_menus()
function add_wp3menu_support() {
 
register_nav_menus(
        array(
        'main-menu' => __('primary'),
        'another-menu' => __('Another Navigation')
        )
     );
 
}
 
//Add the above function to init hook.
 
add_action('init', 'add_wp3menu_support');

Comment: Hi got a fix for now I think, I'm using a base theme called 'Themify Base', it uses flexnav for it's menu. If I figure out anything else on this I'll post here sure.

Comment: Sorry got that theme wrong, use Child's play master, it has a mod version of the flexnav